# how to enable https for my aweb application hosted on google cloud

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, https

I acquired SSL certificate through some certificate authority and later installed on google cloud.
Still, my application is not accessible through https

[www.eventic.in](http://www.eventic.in) works but https://www.eventic.in don't work.

Can you please assist me in enabling https?

I want this site to be available only through https. Even if someone access without https, it should be redirected to https.

[image]

Comment: Where is hosted your webpage? App Engine, a VM, Cloud Storage?

Comment: it is hosted on vm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the image I see you're configuring your certificates in Google App Engine Custom domains. Please note that Compute Engine (where is your VM) and App Engine are different products. Also it is possible that you're following this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl) which is intended for App Engine and not for a VM.

Since you may want to set your certificates in a VM, those configuration remains on the Web server you're using (NGINX, Apache, etc). Also, checking your url `https://www.eventic.in` I'm sure the port `443` is not configured since this port is in general used for `HTTPS`.

You may want to look how to configure an SSL for the solution you have running in your VM

Comment: Thanks @Fervelvet for explaining me the problem. I got your point. I have installed http-server  from here -  https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server. I will search how to  do it on vm/http-server